# What is the correct syntax for accessing a class member function for a pointer-to-class object contained within an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I have the following function, stdDev, which accepts an array of pointers to objects of the Student class. Student class has a member function getScores(), which returns a student's score as a double.

Here is the code below:

```
double stdDev(Student array[], int SIZE) {

    double sum, std_sum, mean, std_mean = 0;
    double *std_scores = NULL;
    std_scores = new double[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {    
        sum += array[i]->getScore;
    }
    mean = sum / SIZE;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        std_scores[i] = pow((array[i]->getScore - mean), 2);
        std_sum += std_scores[i];
    }
    std_mean = std_sum / SIZE;

    return sqrt(std_mean);
}
```

On lines 8 and 13 in the above code, I get the following errors:

```
expression must have pointer type
```

and

```
'*': illegal operation on bound member function expression
```

I'm new to pointer syntax with C++. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You don't have an "array of pointer-to-class objects", you have an array of objects.

Comment: `array[i].getScore()` would be my guess, absent the definition of `Student` class.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is:

```
    sum += answer[i].getScore;
```

Except that you need to call the function (not just refer to it), so it should be:

```
    sum += answer[i].getScore();
```

Other problems:

- You don't initialize `sum` to zero.
- You leak std_scores.  In reverse order of preference:

  - Delete it with `delete [] std_scores` at the end of your function.
  - Declare it as `std::vector std_scores(SIZE);
  - Don't use an array at all.  Just use `double score2 = pow((array[i].getScore() - mean), 2);`

Finally points:

- C++ is not C89 - you should delay declaring your variables until you can give them a value.  `std_scores` is a particularly glaring example of that - you initialize to NULL and then immediately assign a new value.  Apart from `sum` and `std_sum` (and `i`) you don't need any non-const variables.
- The code would be nicer with `std::accumulate`
- There are better algorithms for calculating mean and standard deviation that are more numerically stable.